# Selenium IDE doesn't match text, despite using correct wildcard

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE in Chrome to test a web site. When the test runs successfully, the site produces the text " Success Saving Scenario!" Selenium IDE finds this text, but I can't find the right value to match that text.

Here's my setting:
Command: Assert Text
Target: css-li > span
Value: *Success Saving Scenario*

Each time I run this test, the IDE records a failure with the message:

> assertText on css=li > span with value *Success Saving Scenario* Failed:
> 12:23:02
> Actual value "Thu, 03 Feb 2022 17:23:02 GMT - Success Saving Scenario!" did not match "*Success Saving Scenario*"

I checked the page, and sure enough the text displays Thu, 03 Feb 2022 17:23:02 GMT - Success Saving Scenario!

Why does that not match *Success Saving Scenario*? I thought the asterisks would be a wildcard that would match any characters.

I've tried these values as well with no success:
glob: *Success Saving Scenario*
regexp: *Success Saving Scenario*

- (just an asterisk by itself)

Any ideas?

[image: Selenium IDE screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I would use 'Assert Element Present' for this case. Find another locator from the dropdown with a 'contain' keyword and remove the timezone from the contain keyword as needed. Leave value field empty.

*Sample*
Command: assert element present | Target: xpath=//span[contains(.,'Success Saving Scenario')] | Value: empty